# Is it worth comparing CSP headers with HSTS headers?

Tags: hsts

I am working on a project to add HSTS header to web application.
 As a prework for that, I have added CSP header in report mode only with default-src https directive. The intent is to assess the violations and decide if adding HSTS header is going to break any usecase.
Questions:

1. Is it a worthy approach?
2. What are the scenarios that we will miss for HSTS with this approach?
3. What are recommended approaches, if they are different from what the one I have described above?

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought it was pretty obvious if you are using https only on you server. Do you have https set up? Do you have a redirect set up to force **all** http requests to be redirected to https? These are questions that should be easy to answer by looking at your server config and I don't think you need CSP to answer them. And if the answer to both is not "Yes", then why are you considering HSTS?

CSP support is not universal (though admittedly neither is HSTS) and, with these things, it's usually the older, less common browsers that will break as you'll presumably test the common ones so whether your approach will give you the confidence you need to proceed is debatable.

The one thing you should be aware of is if you are using includeSubDomains flag. This can cause problems if it affects more servers than you intend it to, but CSP will not help as you will presumably only set up CSP on the servers you think will be affected. More info here: https://serverfault.com/questions/665234/problems-using-hsts-header-at-top-level-domain-with-includesubdomains.

Also be aware that, once HSTS is implemented, certificate errors cannot be bypassed in the browser anymore. Not that you should do this, but just another intentional  effect of this flag that not everyone knows about.

Note that the only way to resolve HSTS issues (e.g. If you discover you need http after all), other than to remove the header and wait for the policy to expire, is to set the max age back to zero and hope people visit your site with https to pick up this new HSTS policy and override the previous one. With Chrome it is possible to manually view and remove the policy, but that's not practical if you have any volume of visitors and also not aware of any way to do this with the other browsers short of a full reinstall.

The best approach is to be fully aware of what HSTS is, and the caveats above, and then start with a low expiry, and build it up slowly as long as you do not experience any issues.

There is also the preload list but I would stay well away from that until you've been running this for at least 6 months with no issues.

Comment: In that case HSTS will not break your site as you are already on https only (taking note of the includeSubDomains issue I mentioned above for any subdomains). However even http links will automatically be redirected so CSP will not report anything - except if you are loading 3rd party content on your site over http which will cause you other errors and which HSTS won't help with (except for the small use case of fully qualified http links back to your own site). HSTS takes care of requests. CSP takes care content loaded on the page. Two different uses cases with little overlap.

Comment: The answer to both of your questions is yes.
Let me try to rephrase my question. Is it good to evaluate HSTS using CSP by applying CSP policies where header looks something like:
Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: default-src https:; script-src https: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src https: 'unsafe-inline'; img-src https: data:; font-src https: data:; report-uri <URI>

I will look into the point you have mentioned - related to certificate error.